# How to stop auto update when custom SQL uses parameters

Tags: sql, tableau-api, auto-update

I have a data source in an active connection with custom SQL. The custom SQL contains some parameters in where condition. The dashboard updates several times when select a value for each parameter.

I could disable auto update on desktop version. However, after publish the dashboard, the auto update cannot be stopped. Any ideas to update the dashboard once after all parameters get a value.